# Can I use ES5 Array method at Android2.2+ WebView?

Tags: javascript, android-webview, ecmascript-5, es5-shim

Had read:

http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map

but can't find webview version compatibility such as the one on http://caniuse.com

Comment: I'd gladly include Android results to the table if someone can test.

Comment: Does this https://github.com/AlloyTeam/Mars/blob/master/tools/es5-mobile-compat-table.md help? No Android 2.2 in there though ):